# AsyncTask Crashing on postExecute

Tags: android-asynctask

I have a problem when using asyntask to query all the data in a table and put it in an array List and then send it to the server. I am able to send the data to the server successfully. But the application crashes on the postexecute of the asynctask giving the following error:

```
(W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value ["com.atlantis.eclectics.agentbank.SyncMembersActivity$MemberRecords@41b06d18","com.atlantis.eclectics.agentbank.SyncMembersActivity$MemberRecords@41b070b8"] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject)..
```

What could be problem? Where am i getting it wrong. Someone please help...Thanks very much.

```
package com.practical.tasks.school;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class SyncMembersActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
CustomHttpClient jParser = new CustomHttpClient();
ListView lstView;
public MainDB dbs;
public SQLiteDatabase db;
public static String fname;
String username = "atlantis";
String password = "@t1@ntis";
Button submit;
String statusN = "NO";
String statusY = "YES";
String url = "http://123.456.78.90:1234/Api/create/Post";
String FirstName = "";
String SecondName = "";
String MobileNumber = "";
String DateofBirth = "";
String Gender = "";
String GroupName = "";
String GroupAccountNo = "";
String IdentificationID = "";
String IdentificationType = null;
String CreatedBy = null;
String Residence = "";
private int notificationIdOne = 111;
private int numMessagesOne = 0;
private NotificationManager myNotificationManager;
String account_statusY = "True";
private ProgressDialog prgDialog;


private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sync_members);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeActionContentDescription("Services");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new          ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#5A92F7")));

    lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstSample);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);

    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);


    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                if (isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {

                    new HttpAsyncTask().execute(FirstName, SecondName,    MobileNumber, DateofBirth, Gender, GroupName, GroupAccountNo, IdentificationID, IdentificationType, CreatedBy, Residence);

                } else {
                    showAlert("No internet Connectivity...");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sync_members, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class MemberRecords {

    String FirstName;
    String SecondName;
    String MobileNumber;
    String DateofBirth;
    String Gender;
    String GroupName;
    String GroupAccountNo;
    String IdentificationID;
    String IdentificationType;
    String CreatedBy;
    String Residence;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public String getSecondName() {
        return SecondName;
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return MobileNumber;
    }

    public String getDateofBirth() {
        return DateofBirth;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return Gender;
    }

    public String getGroupName() {
        return GroupName;
    }

    public String getGroupAccountNo() {
        return GroupAccountNo;
    }

    public String getIdentificationID() {
        return IdentificationID;
    }

    public String getIdentificationType() {
        return IdentificationType;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return CreatedBy;
    }

    public String getResidence() {
        return Residence;
    }


    public void setFirstName(String newfirstName) {
        FirstName = newfirstName;
    }

    public void setSecondName(String newSecondName) {
        SecondName = newSecondName;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        MobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setDateofBirth(String dateofBirth) {
        DateofBirth = dateofBirth;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        Gender = gender;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        GroupName = groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupAccountNo(String groupAccountNo) {
        GroupAccountNo = groupAccountNo;
    }

    public void setIdentificationID(String identificationID) {
        IdentificationID = identificationID;
    }

    public void setIdentificationType(String identificationType) {
        IdentificationType = identificationType;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        CreatedBy = createdBy;
    }

    public void setResidence(String residence) {
        Residence = residence;
    }

}

public boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public static String POST(String url, MemberRecords my) {
    InputStream inputStream;
    String result = "";
    String username = "atlantis";
    String password = "@t1@ntis";
    Integer n;

    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://41.186.47.26:4433/Api/Account/PostAddSignatory");

        String json = "";
        Log.e("Url", "Url Here:" + url);


        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("FirstName", my.getFirstName());
        jsonObject.accumulate("SecondName", my.getSecondName());
        jsonObject.accumulate("MobileNumber", my.getMobileNumber());
        jsonObject.accumulate("DateofBirth", my.getDateofBirth());
        jsonObject.accumulate("Gender", my.getGender());
        jsonObject.accumulate("GroupName", my.getGroupName());
        jsonObject.accumulate("GroupAccountNo", my.getGroupAccountNo());
        jsonObject.accumulate("IdentificationID", my.getIdentificationID());
        jsonObject.accumulate("IdentificationType", my.getIdentificationType());
        jsonObject.accumulate("CreatedBy", my.getCreatedBy());
        jsonObject.accumulate("Residence", my.getResidence());

        json = jsonObject.toString();

        Log.e("Url", "Request:" + json);

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        httpPost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
        Header header = new BasicScheme().authenticate(credentials, httpPost);
        httpPost.addHeader(header);
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        if (inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);


        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // 11. return result
    return result;
}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, JSONException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";


    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;


    Log.e("Url", "Response:" + result);

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}

private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        prgDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        dbs = new MainDB(SyncMembersActivity.this);
        db = dbs.getWritableDatabase();
        Integer n=null;

        MemberRecords my = new MemberRecords();
        List<MemberRecords> member_list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_memberData" +
                    " where sync_status = '" + statusN + "' AND account_status = '" + account_statusY + "'", null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    my = new MemberRecords();
                    my.setGroupName(cursor.getString(1));
                    my.setIdentificationID(cursor.getString(2));
                    my.setIdentificationType(cursor.getString(3));
                    my.setFirstName(cursor.getString(4));
                    my.setSecondName(cursor.getString(5));
                    my.setDateofBirth(cursor.getString(6));
                    my.setMobileNumber(cursor.getString(7));
                    my.setGender(cursor.getString(8));
                    my.setGroupAccountNo(cursor.getString(9));
                    my.setCreatedBy(cursor.getString(10));
                    my.setResidence(cursor.getString(11));

                    member_list.add(my);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for ( n = 0; n < member_list.size(); n++) {
             POST(url, member_list.get(n));
        }
        db.close();
        return String.valueOf(member_list);
    }

    //onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    //Response format
    //Response:{"ResponseCode":"00","ResponseMsg":"Successful"}
    //Response:{"ResponseCode":"01","ResponseMsg":"Failed"}
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (String result){
            prgDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Saved Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dbs = new MainDB(SyncMembersActivity.this);
            db = dbs.getWritableDatabase();
            String updateQuery = "Update tbl_memberData set sync_status = '" + statusY + "' where account_status='" + account_statusY + "'";
            db.execSQL(updateQuery);

            String success="";
            String message="";

            try {
                JSONObject jsonBreaker = new JSONObject(result);
                success = jsonBreaker.getString("ResponseCode");
                message = jsonBreaker.getString("ResponseMsg");


                if (success.equalsIgnoreCase("00")) {


                    prgDialog.dismiss();

                    showAlert(message);


                } else if (success.equalsIgnoreCase("01")) {

                    prgDialog.dismiss();
                    //do
                    showAlert(message);

                } else {

                    prgDialog.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error, Please try again...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }


    private void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Server")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


    public boolean isNetworkAvailable(final Context context) {
        final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
        return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }

}
```

Comment: What could be the problem? You are building some sort of JSON data in wrong way - that is what exception says. If you could post stacktrace and point where that exception is thrown

Comment: Dear Team,......I am receiving the response from the server as a JSON response.This is the response i receive: ---- Response:{"ResponseCode":"00","ResponseMsg":"Successful"}. This problem occurs when i try to query all data from the SQLite and put it in a ListArray and send it via the asyncTask at once.......However, when i only query one item and send, this error does not occur

Comment: The error takes place the moment it reaches  JSONObject jsonBreaker = new JSONObject(result); I hope this information will be helpful here. I am really stuck here.

Comment: So I have already predicted that and you got your answer - You are getting JSONArray as response not JSONObject and that is what causing the that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would baste stacktrace and opoint where rxception is thrown would be much easier.
Anyway

Your `result` is probably and `JSONArray` not an `JSONObject` so this

```
JSONObject jsonBreaker = new JSONObject(result);
```

Is causing the exception. Construct `JSONArray` insteed of `JSONObject` and this shoult be fine (this is my blind guess cuz no viable info here)

Comment: Thanks very much Antoniossss. It has worked. I managed to change JSONObject jsonBreaker=new JSONObject(result); to  JSONArray jsonBreaker = new JSONArray(result);
                    success = String.valueOf(jsonBreaker.getString(0));
                    message = String.valueOf(jsonBreaker.getString(1)); and the error is now gone. Thanks very much for your solution

Comment: If this is correct solution, accept the answer (tick on the left) and posibbly upvote (up arrow on the left)